# how to rewrite url in haproxy

Tags: .htaccess, proxy, reverse, haproxy

Hi I am trying to redirect url and access using backend but i struct in configuration my initial configuration is

```
acl url_tag18 path_beg  /v1
       use_backend cdn if url_tag18

backend cdn

   reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ )/v1(.*)    wp/\1
   server web02  24.222.145.72:80 cookie A check
```

I am trying to convert the below url

```
http://example.com/v1/auth_score/ghts/hjk/klk/jkjlj.js
```

to `http://example.com/wp/example.com/v1/auth_score/ghts/hjk/klk/jkjlj.js`

Please help me to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question using below code in haproxy

```
acl url_tag19 path_beg -i  /v1
       use_backend cdn if url_tag19

redirect prefix /wp/example.com if url_tag19
```

Answer (score 0):

Change reqrep in your backend to something like this:

```
reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /v1/(.*)     \1\ /wp/example.com/v1/\2
```

Comment: explain your answer, will help to understand it properly